# Multiple root of characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that V is a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

If V and U are two independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. Must $\lambda$ be a multiple root of $f(x)$, characteristic polynomial.

We know that both of these are in $\ker(T-\lambda T)$ and ${v,(T-\lambda T)v,\dots,(T-\lambda T)^k(v)}$ is a basis for $\ker(T-\lambda T)$. Can we conclude that $u=(T-\lambda T)^i(v)$ for some i, $0\leq i \leq k$?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is always greater than or equal to the geometric multiplicity (which is the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace or, in other words, the number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue). In your case, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is at least two and so $\lambda$ must be a multiple root.